# What can I conclude about $\text{dim}(\text{Ker}(A))$, for a singular matrix $A$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let $A$ be a singular matrix $2\times2$, with entries in $\mathbb{R}$. For instance, suppose that
$$A=\left(\begin{array}{l} a&b\\0&0\end{array}\right),$$
with $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$. Then is $A$ is singular, since $\text{det}(A)=0$.

**Question.** What I can conclude about $\text{dim}(\text{Ker}(A))$?

Here,  $\text{dim}(\text{Ker}(A))$ denote *dimension of* $\:$$\text{Ker}(A)$.

I know that, since $\text{det}(A)=0$, then $\lambda=0$ is the only eigenvalue of $A$. This implies that $\text{dim}(\text{Ker}(A))=1$?

Comment: Ignore my previous comment (it's true... but just ignore it because it unnecessarily added conditions). Here's the main point: since your matrix $A$ is triangular, the eigenvalues of $A$ are the diagonal entries, in this case $a$ and $0$. If $a=0$, then of course there's only one (distinct) eigenvalue, namely $0$. If $a\neq 0$, you have two eigenvalues, namely $a$ and $0$.

Comment: Your comment was quite enlightening. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $(a,b) \neq (0,0)$ then $\dim \ker A = 1$. Otherwise $\dim \ker A = 2$.

The characteristic polynomial is $\chi_A(x)=x(x-a)$. Hence the eigenvalues are $a,0$ if $a \neq 0$ and $0$ otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

A singular matrix, by definition, has a kernel of dimension *at least $1$*. That is all. It means that $0$ *is an eigenvalue*, although it doesn't have to be the only eigenvalue. Without more information, that is all we can say.

With your example $2\times 2$ matrix, if $a\neq0$, then the two eigenvalues are $0$ (with eigenvector $[b, -a]^T$, and kernel spanned by the same vector), and $a$ (with eigenvector $[1,0]^T$). If $a=0$ and $b\neq 0$, then $0$ is the only eigenvalue, but the kernel is the same. If $a=b=0$, then all of $\Bbb R^2$ is the kernel.

Comment: And if $a\neq 0$ and $b\neq 0$, what I can conclude about the eigenvalues?

Comment: @GuillhermedeLoreno That goes under $a\neq 0$, which I already covered.

Answer (score 1):

The $\text{dim}(\text{ker}(A))=1$ if either $a\neq 0$ or $b\neq 0$. It is $2$ if and only if both $a$ and $b$ are $0$. The $\text{ker}(A) = \text{span}([b \;\; -a]^T)$, which is a line passing from the origin $(0,0)$ and the vector $(b,-a)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Moreover, the eigenvalues of $A$ are $0$ and $a$.

Comment: The eigenvalues of $A$ are $0$ and $a$, if either $a\neq 0$ or $b \neq 0$?

Comment: The eigenvalues are independent of $b$ because of the upper triangular structure of the matrix. They'll always be $a$ and $0$, that is, the numbers on the diagonal.

Comment: One more thing. The eigenvalues are not computed from det$A$, but they are the roots of det$(\lambda I -A)$.

Comment: If $A=(a)$, with $a\neq 0$, then what $\text{dim}(\text{Ker}(A))$?

Comment: You mean $A$ is a scalar?

Comment: Yes, a real number fixed and non-zero.

Comment: Then the dimension of ker$(A)$ is 0.

Comment: Because ypu cannot find any nonzero real number $x$ such that $ax=0$.

Comment: Understand. So I can say that the equation $ (A-\lambda) x = 0 $ has no non-trivial solution, for $\lambda=0$?

Comment: And in this case, I can say that the number of zero eigenvalues of $A$ is $0$?

Comment: Yes. In the scalar, where $A=a$, the only eigenvalue is $a$.

Answer (score 1):

You can't say much. For sure you can't say that the only eigenvalue is $0$. For instance the matrix
\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
has the eigenvalue $2$, besides the zero eigenvalue.

Consider the matrix
\begin{bmatrix} e_1 & e_2 & \dots & e_k & 0 & \dots & 0 \end{bmatrix}
where $e_i$ denotes the $i$-th column of the identity $n\times n$ matrix, and there are $n-k$ zero columns at the end.

For $k<n$ the matrix is singular; the dimension of its kernel (or null space) is $n-k$.

So the dimension of the kernel can be anything from $1$ to $n$.

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to give this one a shot because it's been while since is did some linear algebra, here it goes. Let $$A=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}$$ with $|A|=ad-bc=0$ (we consider the most general case with non zero coefficients). Say we have the linear transformation $T:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ with $T(x,y)=A(x,y)$, using the isomorphism theorem $$\dfrac{\mathbb{R}^2}{\ker(T)}\cong Im(T)$$ and since $T(x,y)=\binom{ax+by}{cx+dy}=x\binom{a}{c}+y\binom{b}{d}=(\lambda x+y)\binom{a}{c}$ for certain $\lambda$, $\dim(Im(T))=1$, so $$1=\dim(Im(T))=\dim(\mathbb{R}^2/\ker(T))=\underbrace{\dim(\mathbb{R}^2)}_2-\dim(\ker(T))\Rightarrow\dim(\ker(T))=1$$

Suppose now $b=0$ and $c\neq0$ then $a=0$ or $d=0$, hence $$a=0,d\neq0\Rightarrow T(x,y)=x\binom{0}{c}+y\binom{0}{d}=(\lambda x+y)\binom{0}{d}\quad\text{ for some }\lambda$$
$$a\neq0,d=0\Rightarrow T(x,y)=x\binom{a}{c}$$

in either case $\dim(Im(T))=1$, so $\dim(\ker(T))=1$. Similarly if $c=0$ and $b\neq0$ instead.

It is clear now that if $A$ has only one non zero entry then $Im(T)=span\{\binom{1}{0}\}$ or $Im(T)=span\{\binom{0}{1}\}$, in either case $\dim(Im(T))=1$ so $\dim(\ker(T))=1$.

Finally if $A=0_{2\times2}$, $dim(Im(T))=0$, so $\dim(\ker(T))=2$.

Hope I didn't messed up too bad. thanks